# jenkins API to delete global credentials

Tags: jenkins

I am looking for an API to delete Jenkins global credentials or some other way to delete the global credentials through CLI but cant seem to find any luck.

i got this `https://<jenkins>/credentials/store/system/domain/_/credential/<credetntial>/delete`
but this one is through the web UI.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
curl -X POST "https://<user>:<APItoken>@<jenkinsurl>/credentials/store/system/domain/_/credential/<credetntial>/doDelete"
```